# Minimizing a norm on a ball for another norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Here is a question I do not manage to solve. Let E be a Banach space endowed with two equivalent norms say $N_1$ and $N_2$. Let us consider $a\in E$ and $R\in (0,N_1(a))$ and let $B$ be the closed ball, for the first norm $N_1$, centered at $a$ and of radius $R$ (note that $0\not \in B$). The question is the following one : does the function $f:x\in B\mapsto N_2(x)$ admit a minimum ?

The answer is yes if $N_1=N_2$ and is quite easy (choose $x=ta$ for a suitable $t>0$). However I suspect that the answer is negative in such a generality with two norms (though assumed to be equivalent).

Thanks !